# AVPlayer does not show Video Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I want to play a video using AVPlayer.Problem is video screen does not appear but sound come. It show black screen only.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSUserDefaults *prefs=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    //[prefs URLForKey:@"marge_video_url"];

    AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[prefs URLForKey:@"marge_video_url"]];

    AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];

    self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:item];

    self.playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.player];
    self.playerLayer.contentsGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;
    self.player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

    [self.VideoLayerView.layer addSublayer:self.playerLayer];

    [self.player play];

    self.videoPlaybackPosition = 0;
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    self.playerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.VideoView.frame.size.width, 250);
}
```

This same code i used another controller and can play video nicely. But here this code not working.

Comment: Your code works for me fine. How did you create VideoLayerView?

Comment: @RomanPodymov I used storyBoard and there i add a view called VideoLayerView.

Comment: Can you see that view without a player? Add some background colour and check if you can see it.